# Linux: Comparing two files but not caring what line only content

Tags: linux, diff, comm

I am trying to use comm or diff Linux commands to compare to different files. Each file has a list of volume names. File A has 1500 volumes and file B has those same 1500 volumes plus another 200 with a total of 1700. I am looking for away to just find those 200 volumes. I dont care if the volumes match and are on different lines, I only want the mismatched volumes but the diff and comm command seem to only compare line by line. Does anyone know another command or a way to use the comm or diff command to find these 200 volumes?

First 5 lines of both files: (BTW there is only one volume on each line so File A has 1500 lines and File B has 1700 lines)

File A:

```
B00004
B00007
B00010
B00011
B00013
```

File B:

```
B00003   
B00004   
B00007    
B00008    
B00010
```

So I would want the command to show me B00003 and B00008 just from the first 5 lines because those volumes are not in File A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk can also help.

```
 awk  'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$1; next}!($1 in a) {print $0}' fileA fileB
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me, I also realized the diff -i also works well too

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
comm -23 <( sort largerFile) <(sort smallerFile)
```

This assumes that your Vol name will be the first "field" in the data. If not, check `man sort` for ways to sort files on alternate fields (and combinations of fields).

The `<( ....)` construct is known as process substitution. If you're using a really old shell/unix or reduced functionality shell (dash?), process substitution may not be available. Then you'll have to sort your files before you run `comm` and manage what you do with the unsorted file.

Note that as `comm -23` means "suppress output from 2nd file" (-`2`) and "suppress output from the two files in common" (`-3`), the remaining output is differences found in file1 that are not in file2. This is why I list `largerFile`  first.

IHTH